# How do you capitalize a char in a string using recursion?

Tags: java, string, recursion, uppercase

I'm currently learning Java recursion for the first time, and am stuck on a problem. The task is to receive a string s and char x, and capitalize the character x if it appears in the string, as well as make all non-x characters lowercase. (i.e. Digging returns diGGinG if x is 'g'). Right now, my code returns "iggingggingGINGINGngg"

I know the code is probably quite flawed, but there aren't many similar recursion problems available and I'm not sure where to start with my mistakes. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
public class Capitalize {
public static String capitalize(String s, char x) {
    if(s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    String ans = "";
    if(s.charAt(0) == x) {
        ans += s.substring(1).toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
        ans +=s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ans + capitalize(s.substring(1), x);
}

public static void main(String[]  args) {
    System.out.println(capitalize("Digging", 'g')); //return diGGinG
}
```

}

Comment: To solve a recursive problem you need to tart by thinking of the base case. What is the base case for your problem?

Comment: What do you think `"Digging".substring(1)` returns?

Comment: Would the base case be if char x is not in the string at all? And would "Digging".substring(1) return "D"?

Comment: Strings in java are immutable, so you should think about what that means as well.

Answer (score 2):

there is a misunderstanding of the use of substring

```
System.out.println("Digging".substring(1)); // output : igging
```

To get the only first element you should use :

```
System.out.println("Digging".substring(0,1)); // output : D
```

Try this instead :

```
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(capitalize("Digging", 'g')); // output : diGGinG
    
 }
public static String capitalize(String s, char x) {
    if(s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    String ans = "";
    if(s.charAt(0) == x) {
        ans += s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
        ans +=s.substring(0,1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ans + capitalize(s.substring(1), x);
}
```